# Minimizing properties of geodesics problem in do Carmo's book

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm DoCarmo's book Riemannian Geometry and in the section with minimizing properties of geodesics it this proposition.
[image]
I don't understand why $\langle\frac{\partial f} {\partial r},  \frac{\partial f} {\partial t} \rangle=0$. Can someone fill in the details?

This is the Gauss lemma that he is talking about. 
[image]
So my question becomes, how did he apply this lemma in order to obtain that inner product equal to zero.

Comment: Hi, you can actually edit your previous question instead of asking a new one (this would bump the question to the first page again). I read your comment two days ago but don't have time to write up an answer.

Comment: some discussion [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21779/99914)

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks!! this is what I will do in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  $f(r,t) = \exp(rv(t))$, hence by the chain rule$$
\partial_r f(r_0,t_0)=(d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[v(t_0)]
$$
and
$$
\partial _t f(r_0,t_0)=(d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[r_0\dot v(t_0)].
$$
Hence
$$
\langle \partial_r f(r_0,t_0)\vert \partial_t f(r_0,t_0)\rangle = \langle (d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[v(t_0)]~\vert~ (d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[r_0\dot v(t_0)]\rangle\\ =r_0^{-1}\langle (d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[r_0v(t_0)]~\vert~ (d\exp_p)_{r_0v(t_0)}[r_0\dot v(t_0)]\rangle \overset{\text{Gauß}}{=} r_0^{-1} \langle r_0 v(t_0) \vert  r_0\dot v(t_0) \rangle. 
$$
The latter is zero as it is a multiple to the derivative of $t\mapsto \langle v(t)\vert v(t) \rangle \equiv 1$.

Comment: This was very clear! Thanks!